# How do you prove $x^{x+1}>{(x+1)}^x, x>c$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

It is visible the left side is bigger simply because it's a higher power but calculating the first derivatives leads back to almost the same inequivalence. I tried to prove it with induction which also didn't quite lead anywhere. Any ideas?

Edit: c is some constant. If it's a problem, use c=3 (it's slightly less I believe but definitely >2).

Comment: $x > c$? What is $c$?

Comment: $c=2.71828..$ Take logarithms.

Comment: @zhoraster Wolframalpha says it's 2.29317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to prove it for $x>e$, so prove that $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is a decreasing function for $x>e$.

Comment: First, it's better to prove $x^{1/x}$ is an increasing function in $(0;e]$ and decreasing in $(e;+\infty)$. Secondly, the task is to find the least $c>0$ such that $x>c\implies x^{x+1}>(x+1)^x$, which is about $2.29317$.

Comment: Well, I didn't quite ask for the least c but yes that'd be nice. This is already great progress compared to running around in circles.

Comment: @chx The inequality is equivalent to $x^{1/x}>(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}$. After you notice that the function $x^{1/x}$ is increasing in $(0;e]$ and decreasing in $(e;+\infty)$, you're left with solving the equation $x^{1/x}=(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}$, which has the root $\approx 2.29317$ according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(x%2B1)%3D(x%2B1)%5Ex).